# What are the secret achievements in C&C Rivals?

Tags: command-and-conquer-rivals

There are 13 achievements in C&C Rivals, of which I have unlocked the following:

1. Nod Has Arrived - Unlock Nod
2. Protect Your troops - Link your account
3. Advanced Training - Rank up a unit to level 5
4. Making Friends - Join an alliance
5. Basic Training - Complete tutorial
6. Expert Soldier - Win 100 Battles
7. A Price On Your Head - Collect 100 Bounties
8. A Friend In Need - Donate 100 cards

I did some research and discovered a list of all the achievements [here](https://www.exophase.com/game/command-conquer-rivals-android/achievements/) but according to it I should have unlocked the following achievements:

- Hardened Veteran - Get to Player Level 10 (I am level 46)
- Bring in the Big Guns - Unlock 3 Epic Units (Unlocked 15 epic units)
- Two Heads are Better than One - Unlock 2 Commanders (Unlocked 7 commanders out of 8)
- The Grand Army - Rank up 20 different  units (Ranked up 43 different units,  over 20 in each faction)

I haven't unlocked any of the 4 above, so either the list I found is not correct/out of date or I am experiencing a bug. Can anyone confirm what the remaining 5 secret achievements are and how to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked about this issue on a recent AUAA with the developer on Reddit and they confirmed that the achievements are buggy and that they are working on a fix.

[image: r/cncrivals]